# RegisterEventSource returns NULL, error code is zero

Tags: winapi, windows-server-2008, event-log

Sometimes when I call `RegisterEventSource()`, it returns NULL. `GetLastError()` returns 0.

The event log is on a remote machine in the same domain, and the user is an admin in the domain. This happens several times in a row on different machines (but with the log on the same machine), then stops happening.

Why can this happen?

All machines have Windows Server 2008 running. I'm using C++.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the log machine was temporarily unavailable.